# Default value for debug mode in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

I have web.config as below

```
 <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Is this equal  to debug = true or debug = false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equal to release version (debug = false).